# Electric Field From a point P

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

A rod of length $L$ and total charge $Q$ creates an electric field at a point $P$, $x$ units away.  We need the electric field at this point.
I am working on a physics problem for homework and the set up picture looks like this

[image: Problem Diagram]

I am able to set everything up including identifying my system as being the point on the line, realizing that there is no symmetry that can help, assuming that it is a uniform charge distribution so that I can say that $\lambda = Q/L$.  I have my integral set up in terms of $\mathrm dy$ (which I chose to identify as the little piece of the overall length $L$)  so what I am left with is the following integral

$$ \int_{y=0}^L \frac1{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\cdot\frac{\lambda y}  {(y^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} \, \mathrm dy $$

I am getting a negative answer though which doesn't make any sense considering that my $x$ component is pointing in the positive $x$ direction with the way that I defined my frame of reference.  Any help with this would be great I just want to make sure that the integral I set up with the limits I chose will give me the correct $x$ component of the electric field at this point.

Comment: Hi Samuel and welcome to Physics.SE! Please see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) help post to learn how to write your equations in a way nicer way i.e. in $\LaTeX$, in order to improve legibility. I did it for you this time but in the future it would be better that you did it yourself. Thanks!

Comment: Are you not finding the y component of the E-field which not unreasonably is negative? Now work out the x  component.

Comment: No I am computing the x component and getting a negative, do my limits of integration seem okay?

Comment: Nevermind I found the answer to my question thank you!